# React Typescript memoized callback as prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that displays data returned from a callback received in the props.
I am hoping there is a way to force the use of memoized callbacks so a useEffect hook does not run infinitely due to accidental passing of anonymous functions.

```
const DataRenderer = (props: {asyncDataFn: () => Promise<object[]>}) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);    

    useEffect(() => {
        props.asyncDataFn().then(r => setData(r)),
    [props.asyncDataFn]);

    ...
}


const ShowData = () => {
    // TypeScript should warn here and say that my callback isn't memoized
    return <DataRenderer asyncDataFn={() => return [{...}]}/>
}
```

Is there a way to make the asyncDataFn type something like:

```
asyncDataFn: Memoized<() => Promise<object[]>>
```

Comment: Why does `DataRenderer` receive a callback rather than the actual data? That would be simpler, and bypass the problem of the infinite loop.

Comment: I am planning on enhancing it later to automatically add progress bars and abort signals for fetching data from a remote api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think TypeScript has anything built in for this, not least because "memoized" is a relative term.

I would make `ShowData` responsible for getting the data, and have it give `DataRenderer` the actual data, not a callback to request it. Simpler, and it bypasses the problem with the infinite render loop.

If you don't want to do that and you want a type-based solution, you could brand functions you consider memoized. Here's the `Memoized` type and a hook to do the memoization:

```typescript
type Memoized<T> = T & {__memoized__: true};

const useMemoized = <FunctionType extends () => unknown,>(fn: FunctionType, deps: DependencyList | undefined) => {
    const x = useMemo(fn, deps) as Memoized<FunctionType>;
    x.__memoized__ = true;
    return x;
};
```

Note that this doesn't ensure **proper** memoization (because that's context-sensitive), purely that the function has been asserted to be memoized.

Here's what `DataRenderer` would look like (with a couple of typos fixed as well):

```typescript
const DataRenderer = (props: {asyncDataFn: Memoized<() => Promise<object[]>>}) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState<object[]>([]);    

    useEffect(() => {
        props.asyncDataFn().then(r => setData(r));
    }, [props.asyncDataFn]);

    // ...
};
```

Now this works:

```typescript
const ShowData = () => {
    // Works
    const asyncDataFn = useMemoized(async () => { return [{/*...*/}]; }, []);
    return <DataRenderer asyncDataFn={asyncDataFn}/>
};
```

But this raises an error as desired:

```typescript
const ShowData = () => {
    // Error as requested
    const asyncDataFn = async () => { return [{/*...*/}]; };
    return <DataRenderer asyncDataFn={asyncDataFn}/>
    //                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ Type '() => Promise<{}[]>' is not assignable
    //                               to type 'Memoized<() => Promise<object[]>>'.
    //                               Property '__memoized__' is missing in type
    //                               '() => Promise<{}[]>' but required in type
    //                               '{ __memoized__: true; }'.(2322)
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=1&pln=34&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeBXAZyQFkkQJtCkBlGFGJSogUQDNWkNsARJMJAHYATQWgCeAGWAEYAXzisoEEHABEUVBlUBuAFC6YY-nFLlgALyRCAPABUAfHAC8cW3ABkuAPpeQZCBZWPgBccDBQeEiyerpoEAIycFSmAZZCznDWAGJ4AhjA8bZGSHBIAB4MwgRwABQAlM6OuQDWAhAA7gKY9jWsAqE5eTAFAkX82CJgBKG8-MKiktLwAD5J86zAAlYNTo44unCHcHEJ8GUZyf69XXCTBA0o1SmBNoP5hcX2ekdwZQB0Pj8ZjSPgy4Ui3yOGhgeCgAl+emi+hOiW49BQyHmGigGRqYCUU1COEeYjyaLoWX6Jn8L2s9UacAACkoQNIkNYIAAjABWnBgAG0ALr2eyyHZ7A5HFHwflCdHYIgwckoQUXIi0ejsrm8jBCnpCuraH76H5UNgcDA1em7XCSn6HfEQKZ-Elk9GU+p-GAAC0ENRxNsVyv9dUNdrgsmw-MdztdaGVlMFYfDAHoU3A-pmTVCkDC4ZkhMAAG5wFNfXRI2LxRLUb0dZUARlx4ttPzTcAA6tBmgRw9K4HGE-CXJdgVYanHai2cHBobD4fycCmAFSZv7LlOyQVGyNwA2Qw5z-PWZWYkTYgcEUnx90CJzEq9uikCWRlisxfu1+vogBMzYZ+xtumzBQEoOKPLOSAAI6RDIVh9tW8CDreGSTtaeyQXmC5LqumYbluO4Hph86ZKegjnkg4GPjez73shz6vvY766EAA)

Again, though, I don't think I'd do it that way without some strong driving factor.

Comment: Even though I am convinced now that my approach is wrong, I still love the idea.

Until the strong driving factor is discovered (which I believe could be somewhere out there), here are some extra thoughts:

I'll just swap out the __memoized__ for a unique symbol to ensure no conflicts can occur with the attributes.

const memoSymbol: unique symbol = Symbol();
type Memoized<T> = T & { [memoSymbol]: true };

Comment: If we want to be even more bonkers:

declare module "react" {
  function useMemo<T>(
    factory: () => T,
    deps: DependencyList | undefined
  ): Memoized<T>;

  function useCallback<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
    callback: T,
    deps: DependencyList
  ): Memoized<T>;
  
}